# How do I append a line to the beginning of a very large file in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I have a large text file of ~45 GB, and need to append a line both at the beginning and at the end of the file. What is the quickest way to accomplish this? I don't have access to any big data framework such as Hadoop, etc.

In addition, if I have to also do a string replace in this large file, is there a similar efficient way?

I tried with echo command and it really is taking ages.

Comment: There's no such thing as "inserting" into a file, since that means moving the contents of bytes 0:N to the bytes M:N+M.  Current filesystems don't have an API for this, so you're stuck with rewriting the entire file.  "Speed" will, in this case, boil down to processing everything you want in a single pass.  The time will be how long it takes your disk system to read and write 45GB.

Comment: Why do you have a 45GB text file?  For reasons already mentioned, plus lack of random access, it's a terrible way to store that much data.

Comment: It is actually a Wikipedia dump downloaded as a single XML file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to add a line in the beginning:

```
sed -i '1s/^/your heading line\n/' file
```

And to the end:

```
echo "my new line" >> file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
bye

$ sed -i '1s/^/new line sample\n/' a

$ cat a
new line sample
hello
bye


$ echo "my new line" >> a

$ cat a
new line sample
hello
bye
my new line
```

Comment: I dont find this to be fast. It still is running.

Comment: Ideally, as we are adding a line only at the beginning, I think there should be an innovative way of accomplishing this with some tool/capability, other than the usual sed, awk or other scripts. It should take only few seconds.

Comment: Then you'd better look for it instead of making other ones guess for you.

Comment: Adding a line only at the beginning means rewrite the entire file. It can't take only few seconds.

Comment: So @AbhishekShivkumar, how did it end up?

Comment: I wrote a Hadoop job to complete it in 3 mins :)

Comment: OK @AbhishekShivkumar so consider accepting an answer or editing the question so that people entering in the future can know what worked to you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed -e '1ifoo' -e '$abar'
```

and this would insert `foo` at the top of the file and `bar` at the end of the file.

```
$ seq 5 | sed -e '1ifoo' -e '$abar'
foo
1
2
3
4
5
bar
```